# US Company paying for services provided by a foreign company

Tags: taxes, foreign-income, private-company

I (Company) have been paying a foreign company for their work on few of our software products. I expected that it is a expense from our end, The payments over the times roughly adds up to 150K and I did not with hold any.

So, That foreign company has to pay taxes to the US government or what does it has to do with my company?

Comment: The other company should pay taxes in its country. Yours can declare the 150K as expense.

Comment: @Carlos2W do I have to collect a W-8 or something form the foreign company?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to collect anything from the other company.  I assume they sent you invoices which you then paid.  Those invoices and receipts are enough to establish that this is a legitimate expense for your own taxes.  Whether the company you paid properly pays its own taxes is their issues, not yours.